# How to used windows free HD space in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, hardware

I have install Ubuntu. And my HD size is 360 GB. I have used 250 GB HD for windows and 110 GB for Ubuntu. My space for ubuntu is full. But I have 100 GB free space in Windows. I want to use that space for Ubuntu. Is it possible or not ?

or Should I have to reinstall ubuntu new with HD partition. But I don't think this is good idea ? I don't want loss my data of ubuntu.

Comment: What about mounting NTFS Windows partition and using it from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to permanently add more space to ubuntu partition you must only resize them.

You have nice tutorial [here](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions).

But you can only mount windows partiton, and use them from ubuntu.
Way to mount ntfs partition in ubuntu you have described [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mounting-windows-partition-onto-ubuntu-linux/).

If you wish some third solution you must be more precise with your request,

Comment: Remember to defrag the NTFS partition before resizing - this would make the resizing process faster and more reliable.